# How to keep a count of active Python and Qt threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, thread-safety, qthread

I did a code with PyQt (appended below) which is supposed to create threads and count how many of them are active when you click a button. Since there is a time.sleep(1) inside each thread, i should be able to click the button fast enough so that the active_threads count would increase before diminishing when each thread is finished.

However, no matter how fast i click the button i see only the number 1 printed on the terminal. I looked at the threading documentation and about active_count() it says:

> Return the number of Thread objects currently alive.

So i suppose QThreads do not use thread objects, but some other implementation. I found nothing about counting QThreads in the QThread class documentation. What is the best strategy? Is there anything better than storing threads in a list and removing them of the list at the end?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, threading, time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

threads=[]

class Example(QThread):

    def run(self):
        print(threading.active_count())
        time.sleep(1)

def thread_creator():
    new_thread=Example()
    threads.append(new_thread)
    new_thread.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('QHBoxLayout')
layout = QHBoxLayout()
my_widget=QPushButton('Eat healthy!')
my_widget.clicked.connect(thread_creator)
layout.addWidget(my_widget)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Thread` and `QThread` are just wrapper objects for managing *system* threads. As the Python documentation you quoted states, `active_count` is a count of Python `Thread` objects, not system threads. Obviously there may be many other threads active on your system that were created by other processes, or by other libraries used by your program (such as Qt). So you need to decide which particular subset of threads to count. Qt may create threads internally in addition to the ones you created yourself, so you may not want to count those as well...

If you want to count only those threads you started yourself, you already have `active_count` for the Python threads. For the Qt ones, you could use [QThreadPool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html). Another possibility might be to use a central [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) which could be accessed by all your threads.

Comment: Thanks! I noted, however, that i might have commented hastily about it being exactely what i was looking for: i tried implementing print(QThreadPool().globalInstance().activeThreadCount()) or print(QThreadPool().activeThreadCount()) inside the thread but it just prints 0 in the terminal no matter how many times i press the button. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: No, it's designed to be used with `QRunnable`, rather than `QThread`. Qt doesn't keep a global count of `QThread` instances created by the user like Python does. Instead, it gives you the tools to do the job yourself.

Comment: But, really, you should thinking in terms of *tasks* rather than threads. So you put a bunch of tasks (of unknown length) in a queue, and then create a smallish pool of threads to process them. As each thread completes, it pulls another task from the queue (which is thread-safe) until they are all done. Creating large numbers of threads has a potentially large overhead, and can quite quickly become very inefficient if the system has only one or two cores. It's a mistake to think in terms of creating one thread per task (unless the number of tasks is very small).

Comment: Your last answer indeed does sound efficient and more reproducible in other codes that are not PyQt based. I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - I might have better said you need *two* central queues. One for pending tasks (data in), and another for completed tasks (data out - possibly including error messages).